# jaydata not working in related data storage

Tags: javascript, storage, relation, jaydata

I am new to jaydata and just learned through many tutorials and examples how to define model and store data using JayData. I have written a code which would store data on local storage and it has two entities with one to many relation with each other. I have checked my code many times and also compared it with the available example codes and it is right code but it is not working. the problem is that when I push the single entity into the array which is defined in the other entity model, it does not save the changes and if I comment that push line, everything works fine. I have created a jsfiddle and I have commented that line in my js code.

The code is like this:

```
var task_entity = new Tsk({Task_work:tsk });
mydb.tasks.add(task_entity);

var category_entity=new Categry({Name:ctgry});
category_entity.taskk=new Array();         
//category_entity.taskk.push(task_entity);  // this line is not working

mydb.categorys.add(category_entity);
```

I have commented the line that is creating problem

Here is the jsfiddle 
`http://jsfiddle.net/zGqyZ/1/`

Please let me know what is wrong with the code or may be with the jaydata model, I can't find the main problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only websql/sqlite supports navigation at this moment, this will change really soon

Comment: thanks a lot Gabor Dolla, I was so much worried about it. I also expect more help from you in future as I found you answering many questions on this forum specially regarding JayData.
Thanks again!!